# Does Reactive Strike counts as an effect, for purpose of Frigid Flurry

Tags: spells, pathfinder-2e, opportunity-attack, reactions

[Frigid Flurry](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=916) description end with this specific wording:

> The wind then picks you up and carries you to the other end of the area; though your movement within the gust can still trigger reactions, the storm of ice crystals prevents you from being affected by any effects, except for those that would counteract the spell's magic or that the GM decides would affect snow.

I've heard an interpretation, that "any effects" include only effects that are on the ground, and would cause an effect when you step on it, thus Reactive Strike would work as normal, hitting and dealing damage. I'm not so sure if this is the case, so here is a question:

**Can you be damaged by Reactive Strike caused by movement from Frigid Flury, and if so, when?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Reactive Strike is an effect

[Everything is an effect, essentially](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=350&Redirected=1). Even drawing a sword!

> **Anything you do in the game has an effect**. Many of these outcomes are easy to adjudicate during the game. If you tell the GM that you draw your sword, no check is needed, and the result is that your character is now holding a sword. Other times, the specific effect requires more detailed rules governing how your choice is resolved. Many spells, magic items, and feats create specific effects, and your character will be subject to effects caused by monsters, hazards, the environment, and other characters.

So Reactive Strike would qualify as an effect. There is no wording within the spell that indicates that "grounded" effects is the interpretation here; I'm not sure where that's being derived.

### Reactive Strike may still trigger

Ultimately, while I as a GM would not allow Reactive Strike here, there is the fairly ambiguous line: "that the GM decides would affect snow." There *is* a case that, say, a sword does affect snow. Or perhaps a flaming sword. So you'll ultimately have to consult with your GM.

Comment: I think it would be more clear to say that the damage of a Reactive Strike is an effect. The Reactive Strike's Strike is the cause (not that cause is a game term, but it succinctly covers the fact that everything that happens is an effect)

Comment: @Ifusaso I think that saying attacking (rolling to hit), is an effect caused by use of Reactive Strike action, not the damage itself.

Comment: It might be overkill, but citing the [outline of rules elements](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=2026&Redirected=1), specifically "This section describes the **effects** or benefits of a rules element. **If the rule is an action, it explains what the effect is** or what you must roll. If it's a feat that modifies an existing action or grants a constant effect, the benefit is explained here." might be a good direction.